# Trying to pass an a type to CDK Event Rule RuleTargetInput but the output json has slashes

Tags: c#, aws-lambda, aws-cdk

I have a class that I want to fill then pass to an event rule as payload. like this.

```
public class Payload
{
    public string Site {get;set;}
    public string Region {get;set}
    ....
}
```

now in my CDK I fill these with other values

```
var payload = new PayLoad()
payload.Site = "NY";
payload.Region = "1"
....

var _json = JsonSerializer.Serialize(payload )
```

Now, I want to pass this the RuleTargetInput for the event rule

```
eventRule.AddTarget(new LambdaFunction(fn, new LambdaFunctionProps
{
Event = RuleTargetInput.FromObject(_json )
}));
```

And the event shows something like this

```
"{"\Site\":\"NYC\",\"Region\"}"....
```

The lambda function does not like this payload. if I manually remove the backslashes then it works.
is there a way with System.Text.Json to remove the backslashes on Serialize?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like a json string is passed 'FromObject' as an object  or FromText from a json serializer, the output will have the escape charactres "

according to this github issue [Git Hub issue](https://github.com/aws/aws-cdk/issues/16344)

So the solution is to convert to a dictionary then pass it to RuleTargetInput

```
var rootDictionary = new Dictionary<string, object>();
rootDictionary.Add("Site",item.Site);
rootDictionary.Add("Region",item.Region);
... other list to this
```

then

```
Event = RuleTargetInput.FromObject(rootDictionary)
```